# not able Concat select Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select 'HP00'+ select CAST(select((select count(policyIdPolicy) 
from #temp where policyIdPolicy Not like 'Hp%')-
(select count(policyIdPolicy) from #temp 
where policyIdPolicy like 'Hp%')) AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: If you use `CONCAT()` you won't have to do the `cast` to `varchar` yourself. It also has build in NULL handling.

Answer (score 1):

Select each part separately and then concat.

**Query**

```
select 'HP00' + cast((t.col_1 - t.col_2) as varchar(max)) from(
    select 
    sum(case when policyIdPolicy like 'Hp%' then 1 else 0 end) as col_1,
    sum(case when policyIdPolicy not like 'Hp%' then 1 else 0 end) as col_2
    from #temp
)t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 'HP00'+  
CAST
(
    (

        (select count(policyIdPolicy) 
         from #temp 
         where policyIdPolicy Not like 'Hp%'
        )
        -
        (select count(policyIdPolicy) 
        from #temp 
        where policyIdPolicy like 'Hp%')

     ) AS VARCHAR(10)
)
```